# Disk I/O controller performance

Tags: virtualization, esxi, disk-controller

I am building an home server with an old HP media center m8125x (link for all specs : http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/documentSubCategory?tmp_rule=23238&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=3442913) and have installed ESX5.5 on it.

I am having speed issues with the VMs on it (one with Untangle and the other with Windows Server 2008 R2). I am pretty sure the slowness is caused by the I/O interface controller on the motherboard (Intel ICH8DH), as both VMs have their own hard disk, and when the Untangle VMs is shut down, the other VM (the one that is very slow) runs perfectly.

Now that I am pretty sure of what is causing the problem, I'd want to know if I would have significant speed gains by investing on a low budget pcie SATA 3 controller (preferably below 50$), and how to set it up. Should I keep one hard disk on the MoBo and the other on the SATA controller, or both on the controller?

Also, any suggestion on the bests low budget pcie SATA 3 controller?

Thanks

Comment: If you have the original 400gb hard drive SATA 3 will do nothing for you.  Upgrading the hard drive will get you better performance.  Upgrading to an SSD will make it SATA 3 necessary and blow the doors of your current hdd.  (500mb/s read 150-450mb/s depending on capacity and manufacturer)  However since your budget is $50 you might be able to get a decent hard drive if you hurry up and get a black friday deal somewhere.

Comment: I don't think the SATA 2 is limiting me as much as the I/O controller. I already have a SATA 3 hdd that I could try, but I think that the I/O controller won't be able to give me more than he already is.

Comment: FYI:  a 400gb hard drive would be **lucky** to get 80mb/s read and 60mb/s write so your below the SATA 1 max of 150mb/s.